# Spring reads property file but values are null

Tags: java, spring, properties-file, spring-properties

I don't really understand the problem here. I'm trying to use a properties file in my Spring Application. The file seems to get read but if I try to read the values I get null.

This is (part) of my context xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:aws-context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/aws/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cloud/spring-cloud-aws-context.xsd">

<tx:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="my.package" />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties" />

<!-- OTHER STUFF HERE -->
</beans>
```

I have my test.properties under src/main/resources

When I try to run it like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath*:META-INF/spring/context-test.xml")
public class SimpleTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(environment);
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty("my.test"));
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
StandardEnvironment {activeProfiles=[], defaultProfiles=[default], propertySources=[systemProperties,systemEnvironment]}
null
```

So I assume I should see something in "propertySources" there besides the system properties right?

Also if I change the xml line to this:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:test.properties2" />
```

I get a FileNotFound exception which means the file itself is loaded? So why can't I load the properties from it?

In the test.properties I have only this:

```
my.test=123456
```

What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property-placeholder doesn't automatically expose properties to the environment. You should inject your property like this:

```
@Value("${my.test}")
private String myTest;
```

Comment: According to the Spring documentation I can access all of these via the Environment object as context.getEnvironment(). Also, your solution works interestingly, but I'd prefer the other way.

Comment: Well I guess the other way is more complicated, I just wanted to access environmental variables which arent defined in my environment but they do in production. But yeah I guess your solution might work. thanks